# Getting value from api dict response

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, tuples

Im using requests with the Bitmex API, im trying to get the lastPrice value from the get requests.

I stored the response into a variable, tried a few ways into pulling the lastPrice value including print(value[1]) print(value['lastPrice'], all of which didnt work, ive been reading for a while now on here and cant seem to find the correct working way to get the value. sorry if this is asked all the time.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/instrument?symbol=XBT&columns=lastPrice&count=1&reverse=true')

value = r.text
print(value)
#print(value[1]) 
#print(value['lastPrice'])
```

The output from this is

```
[{"symbol":"XBTUSD","timestamp":"2019-10-03T22:37:13.085Z","lastPrice":8190.5}]
```

using value[1] just returns the first letter in the print. So for ex [1] returns { and using ['lastPrice'] returns 
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return value is JSON string, you can use [`response.json()`](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) to decode it to python `dict`. Result contains `list` with single element, so you should refer to first element of `list` and then get value from `dict` by key:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/instrument?symbol=XBT&columns=lastPrice&count=1&reverse=true')

value = r.json()
print(value[0]['lastPrice'])
```

Comment: ty very much i tried converting it to json and using the same ways to get a value but i didnt think of adding the [0] before hand, figured this was an easy fix.

Comment: yep i accepted sorry it said i had to wait 10 mins since it was a new account ty for the help.